# How to sent Automatic messages on button press from Firebase console using FCM?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been developing an application for both Android & iOS . I have worked with the Firebase notification and I am aware of notification using legacy server key but my main motive is to use only Firebase console for notification and replace my godaddy server so that I can be able to send notification on button click .

**Question 1:** Is there any Api or SDK available from firebase in which I can send notifications to mobile devices from another server(amazon or godaddy) ?

**Question 2:**  Is there any way or method available from firebase in which I can send notifications to another mobile device having my app installed by tapping a button from one device(basically one to many approach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending push notification from your server refer [FCM Application Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server). Yes, you can send notification from one device to another by using Topics or Upstream Messages (Refer here : [FCM Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

Comment: thanks, but for FCM Application Server, i have to buy an server, but i don't want that. i need mobile app based on firebase only

Comment: You can send FCM Notifications from Android and iOS apps (without using Application Server). It is called **Upstream Messages**. Refer Sending Upstream Messages on Android (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream) and iOS Send your First Message (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message)